# Is there a function like asctime_s() that works for SYSTEMTIME structures in windows?

Tags: c, windows, systemtime

I know I can do this if I have a struct tm structure, but what if I want to do the same thing with a SYSTEMTIME.  I could do this manually but just wondering if there's function that does this already.

Thanks

```
 void PrintTimeSCII(struct tm *time)
 {
     char timebuf[26] = {0};

     asctime_s(timebuf, 26, time);
    printf("%s\n", timebuf);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GetDateFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318086(VS.85).aspx) can be used for this.  It can format the date using the appropriate format for a given locale.  Below code shows how to use it for the user's default locale, in short format.

```
char timebuf[26];
GetDateFormat(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, 
              DATE_SHORTDATE,
              &sysTime,
              NULL,
              timebuf, 
              ARRAYSIZE(timebuf));
```