# convert SYSTEMTIME to LPCWSTR

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a function like asctime_s() that works for SYSTEMTIME structures in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121734/is-there-a-function-like-asctime-s-that-works-for-systemtime-structures-in-win)

I need to convert a type of `SYSTEMTIME` to a string. Then append the string product onto another string. Then finally convert the final string to type of `LPCWSTR`

All of the properties of the `SYSTEMTIME` are `WORD` types.

I think I need to convert the `WORD` types to `wchar_t` types and then concatenate them to get the string of SYSTEMTIME. How do I do this conversion and concatenation?

Once the final string has been built how can a `LPCWSTR` type be made from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GetTimeFormatEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318131%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`GetTimeFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318130%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) if you need to support Windows XP to format a SYSTEM time to a string.

Comment: thanks shf301, this makes it much easier! I would like to have a complete date-time string, should I use `GetDateFormatEx` in conjunction or is there another function that does both?